# Can I have different callback urls for sign_in and sign_up process in AWS Cognito?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, x-callback-url

I am trying to customize AWS Cognito in a way that after the sign-up process, the user will be redirected to an app API - "create_node_in_DB". This can be easily done by adding a callback url - "localhost:5000\ create_node_in_DB" in the APP client setting in Cognito.

But AWS cognito uses the same callback url when the user tries to just 'sign_in'. This creates multiple nodes in the database for the same user. Is there any way I can have a separate callback url for sign_in or sign_up process. I tried AWS lambda functionality but I have been unsuccessful in finding the solution.

Is there any other approach of solving this problem?